# VS 2008 - Sample Code for comparing and getting range of two dates using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2008

SAMPLE

Due date: June 13, 2013 (exact 6 months)

Date Today: December 13, 2013

QUESTION:

How could I know if due date is less than or equal or above 6 months starting from its due date to the date today? I need sample code using vs 2008.

Any Valuable comments and suggestions are well-appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now for today's date and the AddMonths method handle the six month logic:

```
'Assumes dteDueDate is an instantiated DateTime class with the target due date. 
If DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6) >= dteDueDate Then

          'Due Date is within six months from now.

     Else

          'Due Date is more than six months from now.

End If
```

Comment: Although this works in most cases, `CompareTo` might be a better option if dueDate is passed as an IComparable, in which case `>=` won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much NoAlias but it doesn't work if it is more than 6 months maybe Dan was right. Dan can you give me a sample?

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) I already made the solution, I just made a little bit experiment in the codes gave by NoAlias considering of what Dan said :) Thank you :)